# Which ESLint style guide is closest to TSLint, after migrating to ESLint from deprecated TSlint?

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

**QUESTION** - What's the closest style guide in ESLint coming from TSLint for VSCode with an Angular project? Instead of changing a bunch of rules in .eslintrc.json is there a better out of the box style guide to use that won't give me so many errors?

I configured my style guide with Google (thinking Google is Typescript), but I'm getting lots of errors with this style guide that I wasn't with TSLint.

Ex1. max length for code is 80 -> TSLint was 140 I believe

Ex2. There should be no space after '{'

> import { AfterViewInit, Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

**FYI** - I migrated from TSLint to ESLint in my VSCode Angular project.
I'm getting lots of ESLint errors that I wasn't before. I used these configure options when installing ESLint. ex. Google as the style guide

[image]

Here is my .eslintrc.json file

```js
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "google"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 12
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "max-len": ["error", {
      "code": 140
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin and @typescript-eslint/parser

Comment: I use a combination of the eslint bulit in recommended rules, `@typescript-eslint` recommended rules, and `@angular-eslint` recommended rules with some specific modifications. I don't think there is a total 1-to-1 from tslint to eslint, and it also depends on if you have any additional tslint plugins. Re: formatting such as the brace spacing, I would recommend using a library like `prettier` to handle formatting.

Comment: I have used both eslint and typescript. They can be used together.

Comment: I'm using Prettier in addition to ESLint. Can you please provide (as an answer) steps to install and use the best option for typescript

Comment: Also I do have @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin installed, but not sure about parser. I believe they are both installed as ESLint asked me if I wanted to install them and I said yes. I'll post my .eslintrc.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is better, but I've changed the style guide in my

.eslintrc.json file from

> "extends": ["google"],

to

> "extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],

and this seems to eliminate lots of errors that I never received using TSLint. So it seems like this style might be more similar!?

Any thoughts?